# How to serve both static and dynamic content via AWS cloudfront?

Tags: amazon-s3, dns-zone, ddos, amazon-cloudfront, digital-ocean

I have a site hosted on a digital ocean droplet which serves both static and dynamic content. The static content (e.g. /images, /js, /css, /fonts) is served from an s3 bucket with folders `/images, /js, /css, /fonts` via cloudfront which has a path pattern behaviour of `Default (*)`. To use a custom url for this distribution i added an alternate name of `assets-dev.example.com` and added a cname record in my DNS control panel which points assets-dev.example.com to the cloudfront distribution. This part all works fine.

Now I want to serve the rest of my site e.g. dev.example.com which also serves dynamic content via cloudfront.

I tried to set up a custom origin using domain `dev.example.com` and added another alternate name for the distribution of `dev.example.com`

However in my DNS control panel I have an A record pointing `dev.example.com` to my digital ocean droplet and get an error if I try to add a cname record with `dev.example.com` pointing to the cloudfront url.

So my questions are:

- What's the correct way to configure the DNS settings so that
  dev.example.com is returning content from cloudfront which then gets
  it from my custom origin digital ocean droplet?
- There is an AWS tutorial on how to serve dynamic content using ec2
  and cloudfront
  (https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/getting-started/EC2/) but doesn't
  go into the detail of configuring the DNS settings and his set up
  doesn't cache any content so not sure purpose not caching content in
  his tutorial serves?
- If I have 2 origins defined (s3 and digital ocean droplet) and two
  alternate name (assets-dev.example.com and dev.example.com) how would
  cloudfront know from which origin to serve content from? Note in my
  site the url to return assets is defined as
  https://assets-dev.example.com/js/test.js etc

The only way I can think of is to set up an origin to be something like `content.example.com` and create an new dns record using that name which points to the digital ocean droplet. Then add a CNAME record e.g. dev.example.com which points to the cloudfront distribution. This way users can use `dev.example.com` to view the site content via cloudfront.

The only issue I have with the above set up is that anyone can bypass cloudfront by using content.example.com so how would any benefits such cloudfront ddos protect help in this scenario?